# CSS file not linking to HTML file (same folder)

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```
<head>
<title>1</title>
<link rel=“stylesheet” type="text/css" href=“style1.css”>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

I've tried many things. removing the type, adding a / at the end, adding a ./ before style1.css, etc. Both the html file and the css file are in the same folder. The html works. here is the css:

```
p {
    color: red;
}

h1 {
    color:blue;
}
```

where did I go wrong ?

Comment: it seems that you are using wrong double quotes in the link tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your quotations around your attribute value, just replace your link with below, and hopefully, this should work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style1.css" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. I'll make sure to approve your answer when the 10 minutes counter is over

Answer (score 0):

It seem you are using wrong double quotes symbol in the link tag

```
<link rel=“stylesheet” type="text/css" href=“style1.css”>
```

It should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
```

Comment: Thank you, too. I never noticed there were different quote symbols

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
<link rel=“stylesheet” type="text/css" href=“style1.css”>
```

with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
```

```css
p {
    color: red;
}

h1 {
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <title>1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        </head>
<body>
    <p>this is paragraph</p>
    <h1>this is h1 heading</p>
</body>
</html>
```

your reference to the stylesheet look like this

Comment: Right answer but somewhat confusing, please specify what's exacltly wrong like "...your link to style1.css is correct exept for using the wrong quotes: replace “ marks with simple quotation "